# Is there any elegant way of iterating through a list whose elements' positions can change?

Tags: c++, list

I am currently running into a disgusting problem. Suppose there is a list **aList** of objects(whose type we call **Object**), and I want to iterate through it. Basically, the code would be like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < aList.Size(); ++i)
{
    aList[i].DoSth();
}
```

The difficult part here is, the **DoSth()** method could change the caller's position in the list! So two consequences could occur: first, the iteration might never be able to come to an end; second, some elements might be skipped (the iteration is not necessarily like above, since it might be a linked list). Of course, the first one is the major concern.

The problem must be solved with these constraints:

1) The possibility of doing position-exchanging operations cannot be excluded;

2) The position-exchanging operations can be delayed until the iteration finishes, if necessary and doable;

3) Since it happens quite often, the iteration can be modified only minimally (so actions like creating a copy of the list is not recommended).

The language I'm using is C++, but I think there are similar problems in JAVA and C#, etc.

---

The following are what I've tried:

a) Try forbidding the position-exchanging operations during the iteration. However, that involves too many client code files and it's just not practical to find and modify all of them.

b) Modify every single method(e.g., **Method()**) of **Object** that can change the position of itself and will be called by **DoSth()** directly or indirectly, in this way: first we can know that **aList** is doing the iteration, and we'll treat **Method()** accordingly. If the iteration is in progress, then we delay what **Method()** wants to do; otherwise, it does what it wants to right now. The question here is: what is the best (easy-to-use, yet efficient enough) way of delaying a function call here? The parameters of **Method()** could be rather complex. Moreover, this approach will involve quite a few functions, too!

c) Try modifying the iteration process. The real situation I encounter here is quite complex because it involves two layers of iterations: the first of them is a plain array iteration, while the second is a typical linked list iteration lying in a recursive function. The best I can do about the second layer of iteration for now, is to limit its iteration times and prevent the same element from being iterated more than once.

So I guess there could be some better way to tackle this problem? Maybe some awesome data structure will help?

Comment: Modifying a list while iterating over it is a great way to experience weird behavior or even [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). It might be because of a design problem, or a problem implementing the design.

Comment: Use a list of indexes to store the positions and apply position exchanges after the loop.

Comment: As a possible (and maybe temporary) solution, you could create a *new* container and insert into it as you iterate over the first original container. Then copy over from the new to the original after you're done. Or you could change the iteration to not use iterators but position, which is very easy to do when you have the "default" container `vector`.

Comment: Can any modification of the order happen, or is something about them guaranteed (e.g. always backwards, always forwards)? Can `DoSth` be modified to return the new position?

Comment: @Angew The DoSth() is just a simple function that can be overridden by client codes to do just anything they want. It does not have any return value, nor should it care. As to the position-exchanging issue, in fact, it can happen in any way possible (inside the first iteration layer, inside the second iteration layer, or between them), but I think dealing with only the second layer is enough for me.

Comment: @ThomasSablik In fact, the situation here is dealing with the iteration over a multi-tree. To make things simple, I gave a list example.

Comment: This strikes me as an XY problem.   A member function of an object cannot naturally affect a container which contains that object - it would have taken a deliberate effort to even enable such a thing.   You might want to explain (1) why an object is able to access the container (if any) it is in, and   (2)  since such a thing has been deliberately enabled, why there aren't defined ways to prevent dangerous actions like resizing the container or moving elements around in it.    Since the logical solution to such a problem is simple:  don't allow an object to identify what container it is in.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is a little light on detail, but from what you have written it seems that you are making the mistake of mixing concerns.

It is likely that your object can perform some action that causes it to either continue to exist or not. The decision that it should no longer exist is a separate concern to that of actually storing it in a container.

So let's split those concerns out:

```
#include <vector>

enum class ActionResult {
    Dies,
    Lives,
};

struct Object
{
    ActionResult performAction();
};

using Container = std::vector<Object>;

void actions(Container& cont)
{
    for (auto first = begin(cont), last = end(cont)
        ; first != last
        ; )
    {
        auto result = first->performAction();
        switch(result)
        {
            case ActionResult::Dies:
                first = cont.erase(first);  // object wants to die so remove it
                break;

            case ActionResult::Lives:       // object wants to live to continue
                ++first;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

If there are indeed only two results of the operation, lives and dies, then we could express this iteration idiomatically:

```
#include <algorithm>

// ...

void actions(Container& cont)
{
    auto actionResultsInDeath = [](Object& o)
    {
        auto result = o.performAction();
        return result == ActionResult::Dies;
    }; 

    cont.erase(remove_if(begin(cont), end(cont), 
                         actionResultsInDeath),
               end(cont));
}
```

Comment: Using remove_if + erase would make the code even simpler.

Comment: @paler123 Updated, but 2 things to say on this: first is that it's more idiomatic if the OPs problem has only two outcomes (he doesn't say whether he wants to insert or reorder, which would be more problematic) and second is that it's second nature for you and me, but probably not the OP.

Comment: XY problem  (obviously).  We need to be asking _why_ the OP feels he needs to pull a crazy stunt like this.

Comment: Well, seems it will take me a little while to digest the code here. As to the problem given here, only the reorder is my concern, the insertion or deletion does not matter (they have already been dealt with elegantly).

Comment: @SuperSaiyanGod the same prinicples apply. The eventual reordered container is a separate issue to that of the ordering predicate. It sounds as if what you really want to do is perform a sort? It's difficult to comment further as I don't have details of the actual motivating use case.

Comment: @SuperSaiyanGod If the actions are other than `lives` and `dies` like reordering as mentioned, then it looks like a design problem, like why and how does `DoSth()` even know about `aList`?

Comment: @GauravSehgal Well, it does look like a design problem, but that makes sense to me. The action done in DoSth() indeed cause some effect to the caller; the reorder of aList is some side-effect, but it's the best possible way for now. The details are too delicate and beyond the scope of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, problem solved, at least in regard to the situation I'm interested in right now. In my situation, **aList** is really a linked list and the **Object** elements are accessed through pointers. If the size of **aList** is relatively small, then we have an elegant solution just like this:

```
Object::DoSthBig()
{
    Object* pNext = GetNext();
    if(pNext)
        pNext->DoSthBig();

    DoSth();
}
```

This has the underlying hypothesis that each pNext keeps being valid during the process. But if the element-deletion operation has already been dealt with discreetly, then everything is fine.

Of course, this is a very special example and is unable to be applied to other situations.